# Jackson: Override primitive type deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson

We need to process some broken JSON from a legacy server here that wrongly encodes `null` values as literal `"null"` strings in its output.

I already found that I probably want to override https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/ParserMinimalBase.java#L368 to "fix" this, but this seems to be so deep inside Jackson that I'd rather do it differently. Are there alternatives, for example by using the `ObjectMapper` to add a custom deserializer for the `String.class` or am I lost?

Comment: I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it worked by overriding the standard String deserializer. Unfortunately I had to copy the complete implementation over because `org/codehaus/jackson/map/deser/std/StringDeserializer.java` is final and cannot be extended.

```java
public class FixesModule extends SimpleModule {

    public FixesModule() {
        super();
        addDeserializer(String.class, new CustomStringDeserializer());
    }
}
```

and

```java
public class CustomStringDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<String> {

    private static final String NULL_STRING = "null";

    public CustomStringDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonToken curr = jp.getCurrentToken();
        // Usually should just get string value:
        if (curr == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            // BEGIN NULL_STRING fix
            if (NULL_STRING.equals(jp.getText())) {
                return null;
            }
            // END NULL_STRING fix
            return jp.getText();
        }
        // [JACKSON-330]: need to gracefully handle byte[] data, as base64
        if (curr == JsonToken.VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT) {
            Object ob = jp.getEmbeddedObject();
            if (ob == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (ob instanceof byte[]) {
                return Base64Variants.getDefaultVariant().encode((byte[]) ob, false);
            }
            // otherwise, try conversion using toString()...
            return ob.toString();
        }
        // Can deserialize any scalar value, but not markers
        if (curr.isScalarValue()) {
            return jp.getText();
        }
        throw ctxt.mappingException(_valueClass, curr);
    }

    // 1.6: since we can never have type info ("natural type"; String, Boolean,
    // Integer, Double):
    // (is it an error to even call this version?)
    @Override
    public String deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return deserialize(jp, ctxt);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to copy the entire implementation, because you can use composition. Just check for the `null` string first and then delegate to `StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

due to StringDeserializer is Final, we can use another way to process String

use  `StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize()`

here the simple to override string deserializer, and parse null as empty string

```
public class NullStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

@Override
public String deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String s = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(jsonParser, deserializationContext);
    return s == null ? "" : s;
}

}
```