# fasterxml jackson JSON deserialization - custom adding

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I use Jackson FasterXML product to deserialize JSONs. Now, I noticed in profiler that I got a ton of duplicate strings as a result since every time I receive a JSON it deserialize into an object which always contains some String variable which tells me the Type name. (it's answer to Facebook GraphQL query). Now, naturally, I would prefer for .intern() method to be used during deserialization of this specific method. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Simplest decision seems to be using of  JsonValueInstantiator but in the examples that I found it's only used for the whole Class. Is there some simple way to use it with fields?

Answer (score 0):

Seems StringDeserializer can provide whttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041249/jackson-override-primitive-type-deserialization